Flexbox with column is not providing the desired output in CSS
I have an HTML layout styled with flexbox, but the current CSS isn't achieving the desired layout. I want the second row of the second column to begin immediately after the first columns second row.

Here is the code:


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}


.programs {
  background: blue;
}

.programs-2 {
  background: green;
}

.xyz {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 0; /* Prevents growth */
}

.xyz ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.xyz ul .box {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.xyz ul .box:last-child {
  width: 200px;
}

.programs .xyz:first-child ul .box:last-child {
  width: 300px; /* This affects only the first column */
}

/* Remove horizontal spacing on programs-2 */
.programs-2 .xyz {
  margin-left: 0; /* Ensure no margin on left side */
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="programs">
        <div class="xyz">
            <ul>
                <li class="box">
                    ABC
                </li>
                <li class="box">
                    ABC
                </li>
                <li class="box last">
                    ABC
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="xyz">
            <ul>
                <li class="box">
                    ABC 2
                </li>
                <li class="box">
                    ABC
                </li>
                <li class="box last">
                    ABC
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="programs-2">
        <div class="xyz">
            <ul>
                <li class="box">
                    ABC
                </li>
                <li class="box">
                    ABC
                </li>
                <li class="box last">
                    ABC
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="xyz">
            <ul>
                <li class="box">
                    ABC 2
                </li>
                <li class="box">
                    ABC
                </li>
                <li class="box last">
                    ABC
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



Note:- I don't want to change the HTML because the HTML structure depends on specific functionality which I can't change.
I want this output without changing the HTML


Your .programs and .programs-2 are separate columns, you can not just have items move from one to the other with flexbox.

It won't be possible, your rows are wrapped into columns which have specified width. You should use Javascript to manipulate the DOM

I am also thinking that it is not possible. Paulie_D I want the output as the screenshot.

Is there any other way using inline block, inline flex or columns properties which can do this?

Are you able to adjust the HTML? You seem to be deliberately grouping elements into sub-groups that you don't want, which doesn't (seem) to make sense.

I can't modify the HTML where I need this functionality. I am looking for css solution onlyy.

Paulie_D, Every  element has some width and as per my attached screenshot I want the second columns (Green background) second row which starts from ABC2 to be shifted to the the first column (Blue background) second row end. Without changing the widths. Screenshot is simple and clear with directions.

At the very least, please show a picture of exactly what you want (with dimensions, and requirements); "I want it as in the screenshot..." is clearly not working as a description.

I have edited the issue agian and added the desired output screenshot without any HTML update.

You can leverage flex-direction: column and inline-flex


.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.programs {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  ;
}

.programs-2 {
  display: flex;
  background: lightblue;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.xyz {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-grow: 0;
  /* Prevents growth */
  border: 2px solid black
}

.xyz ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.xyz ul .box {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.xyz ul .box:last-child {
  width: 200px;
}

.programs .xyz:first-child ul .box:last-child {
  width: 300px;
}

.programs-2 .xyz {
  margin-left: 0;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="programs">
    <div class="xyz">
      <ul>
        <li class="box">
          ABC
        </li>
        <li class="box">
          ABC
        </li>
        <li class="box last">
          ABC
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="xyz">
      <ul>
        <li class="box">
          DEF
        </li>
        <li class="box">
          GHI
        </li>
        <li class="box last">
          JKL
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="programs-2">
    <div class="xyz">
      <ul>
        <li class="box">
          MNO
        </li>
        <li class="box">
          PQR
        </li>
        <li class="box last">
          STU
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="xyz">
      <ul>
        <li class="box">
          VWX
        </li>
        <li class="box">
          YZA
        </li>
        <li class="box last">
          XXX
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



